# Rails engine constants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, constants, nameerror

I have a Rails engine with the latest rails and ruby.

I have a controller called cms, with a action called update. I use this update action to update different tables. For example I have got a table called setting. This technique works fine in a normal Rails app, but in my Rails Engine it throws this error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Setting):
```

I've got a model called Setting, why is givin me an error  ?

Comment: Where is Setting model located in filesystem?

Comment: it's in the engine, so it should work

Comment: No, in what file is it located? The path is important for autoloading.

Comment: the setting.rb is located here: models/cms/setting.rb - is this what you mean ?

Comment: Yes, is it app/models or just models?

Comment: it's inside root/app/models/cms/setting.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File naming is important for autoloading to work. Naming convention is the same in both apps and engines. In fact, an application *is* an engine.

So, `my_rails_app/app/models/cms/setting.rb` is equivalent to `my_engine/app/models/cms/setting.rb`

If you still have troubles, try accessing constant with explicit namespace `Cms::Setting`.

You can dynamically get constant from an appropriate namespace by doing

```
Cms.const_get(table.capitalize)
```

However, be careful with this approach since a hacker can send you anything and hence access any constant.

Comment: Thanks, I worked fine as it was, the problem was not the model but this did'nt work inside the engine: table.capitalize.constantize, which I use so that I can update different tables from jquery.. This would translate to Setting as a constant, but I guess it needs the namespacing of the engine

Comment: Updated answer. Constantize won't work because it gets constants from the global namespace.

Comment: Awesome! - It works.. thanks. Yeah I'll use a whitelist.. . )